# Material Design TabLayout - tabIndicatorAnimationMode not found

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I'm trying to set from my `layout.xml` the tab attribute described in the following [docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tabs#scrollable-tabs).

The attribute I'm talking about is `tabIndicatorAnimationMode` witch should have 2 option; `linear` and `elastic`. If I search inside the [github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/res/values/attrs.xml) in the attrs.xml file I find them:

```
<attr name="tabIndicatorAnimationMode">
      <!-- Animate the selection indicator's left and right bounds in step with
           each other. -->
      <enum name="linear" value="0"/>
      <!-- Animate the selection indicator's left and right bounds out of step
           with each other, decelerating the front and accelerating the back.
           This causes the indicator to look like it stretches between destinations
           an then shrinks back down to fit the size of it's target tab. -->
      <enum name="elastic" value="1"/>
</attr>
```

**How I'm trying to achive it:**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic">
```

**What version of material design i use?** (currently the lasted available on [maven](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material))

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
```

**What error do i get?**

```
layout.xml:63: AAPT: error: attribute tabIndicatorAnimationMode not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bumping up your version to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-beta01'
```

Answer (score 0):

The version you're using does not include that attribute.
Use the following stable version in order to have access.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'
```